# Downvotes gone after question is closed as Not a real question

Tags: support, down-votes, closed-questions

[image: Screenshot of the question]

---

Downvotes gone after question is closed as Not a real question, also there is no auto downvotes there.

---

[image: Screenshot of the question after closing]

Comment: We have a clear need to test this - let us downvote you to oblivion, close this as off-topic (the other close reason that applies a downvote), and see if that clears your record or not. ♪

Comment: @Grace, go ahead

Comment: -1 Happy to help. :)

Comment: Hmm, `[status-norepro]`. Maybe we need a mod. Or Robert did something crazy.

Comment: Urp...What?....

Comment: @Robert, did you clear the flags after you closed that question as NARQ?

Comment: @YOU: No, just closed it.  But I did do an edit.

Comment: @Robert, do you know there is 4 spam or offensive flags when you close that question?

Comment: @YOU: If you mean the moderator flags, I dismissed them as valid.  It shouldn't be removing the votes, though.  Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @Robert, you dismiss those after you closed the question? If so, looks like automatic downvote for NARQ, OT question also got removed.

Comment: @YOU: Yes, that is my normal workflow.  Take action, then dismiss the flags.

Comment: @YOU: Now that I think about it, it's possible that I accidentally clicked "invalid" rather than "valid."  If that's what I did, then it would be perfectly reasonable to erase the automatic downvotes.

Comment: @Robert, for that case, I couldn't verify it anymore, since I didn't flag it, I mean I can't check my flag weight down or up.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like moderators can remove votes from Community User (downvotes from flags).

Flags are also gone from the flag-list at 10k tools

Comment: How did you...?

Comment: @Grace, just a grace period.